# Retrieve Firebase value and set SKLabelNode text

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is probably a very simple question.
This is the database:

[image]

I want to retrieve this "New" value which is 1 and put on a SKLabelNode.
The problem is that this code is printing 10 correctly but setting nil to SKLabelNode on the emulator.

```
        dbRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if !snap.exists() {
            return
        }else{

            print(snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "New").value!)
            self.label.text = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "New").value as! String?



        }
    }
```

Comment: printing '1' or '10'?

Comment: @NiravD - if that was the problem, wouldn't it just delay updating the label until after the background tasks had finished?

Comment: Im updating the UI, when this code runs, it prints 1 on terminal but updates the label text to "nil"

Comment: Julio, I have created the same database, and run the same code - and it works for me!

silly check - have you tried setting self.label.text = "JUST CHECKING" at the same point, just to make sure you're updating the right thing?

Comment: Hey Russel not I didnt do that... and after done I saw that the label was being executed as well which was causing the error:
let a = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "New").value as? Int
            self.label.text = String(describing: a)

Thanks! Case closed

Comment: @NiravD Firebase callbacks are surfaced on the main/UI thread, so no additional code is needed for that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for this peaceful info :)